# Not able to run Spring MVC Web application after deploying on OpenShift Tomcat?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, openshift

I like to know how to configure my spring mvc configuration xml file to get connected to **openshift** **postgresql** **9.2** database. I already made changes on tomcat configuration file of path *.openshift/config* directory.
Just want to know how can I make connection to the openshift postgresql 9.2 from my spring mvc application deployed on openshift tomcat gear.
Everytime i deploy war on openshift tomcat i get error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:672)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:264)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1201)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:986)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:933)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:851)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

root cause

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:834)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.getJspAttribute(Validator.java:1385)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.checkXmlAttributes(Validator.java:1262)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:876)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1538)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2377)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2429)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:895)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1538)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2377)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2429)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2435)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:474)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2377)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator.validateExDirectives(Validator.java:1841)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:217)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:373)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:657)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:264)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1201)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:986)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:933)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:851)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

What would be the reason for this?? whenever i run this war locally with local DB connection it run fine, but couldn't get what happens when i deploy on openshift tomcat?

In `.openshift/config server.xml` i have code under `GlobalNamingResources` tag is:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/postgresqldb" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
username="${env.OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_USERNAME}"        password="${env.OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_PASSWORD}"
url="jdbc:postgresql://${env.OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_HOST}:${env.OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_PORT}/${env.OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME}"
driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver" initialSize="5" maxWait="5000"
maxActive="120" maxIdle="5" validationQuery="select 1"
poolPreparedStatements="true">
</Resource>
```

and in `.openshift/config context.xml` under Context xml is:

```
<ResourceLink name="jdbc/postgresqldb" global="jdbc/postgresqldb" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
```

and in my spring mvc `servlet-context.xml` is:

```
<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/postgresqldb"/>
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the code you are using to connect with?

Comment: @corey112358 i have provided code i am using for connection..any help??

Answer (score 0):

Check your JSP file for missing or wrong attributes values inside the html tags.

Spring MVC checks for well-formed html tags. If you missed fill any attributes or those attributes have wrong values, it won't run and will give you an error message related to JasperException.

I recommend using the spring tag namespace when using forms:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<form:input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Login" maxlength="10" size="10" path="" name="login"/>
```

Eclipse in this case is very helpful because if something is wrong it will tell you.

Comment: please, try to enhance your answer