# What version of servlet,java and jsp does openshift tomcat 7.0 (JBossEWS 2.0 ) support?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, tomcat7, openshift

As my Spring MVC web app is using

> Servlet version: 3.0
>   JSP version: 2.1
>   Java version: 1.7.0_11

and Had deployed war on **OpenShift Tomcat 7 (JBossEWS 2.0 )** using above version ,it always giving me error :

```
 org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP
 java.util.NoSuchElementException
java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:834)
```

and i tried using version **JSP 2.0 and  Servlet 2.5**..still no use.
Any Help?
**Login.jsp:**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
  <%@   taglib  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"  prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib  uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>  
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>

<section id="page">
            <!-- HEADER -->
            <header>
                <!-- NAV-BAR -->
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                            <div id="logo">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--/NAV-BAR -->
        </header>
        <!--/HEADER -->
        <!-- LOGIN -->
        <section id="login" class="visible">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                <c:if test="${not empty error}">

                    <div class="errorblock" style="text-align:center;">  
                        <b style="text-align:center;">Your login attempt was not successful, try again.</b>
                    </div>
                </c:if>
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                        <div class="login-box-plain divide-40">

                             <form:form    method="post" action="authenticate" modelAttribute="userInfo">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">User Name</label>
                                   <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                                <form:input  path="loginID" id="username" placeholder="" />

                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group"> 
                                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                                <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                                 <form:password class="form-control" path="password" id="password" placeholder=""/>

                              </div>
                              <div>

                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Login</button>
                              </div>
                            </form:form>


                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <!--/LOGIN -->


</section>
```

Comment: Maybe you simply have an error in your JSP file? If you post it here, we can take a look at it.

Comment: @nfechner JSP code which contains error

Comment: Hm, nothing obviously wrong with the JSP. Could you include the full stacktrace please.

Comment: @nfechner [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28679924/not-able-to-run-spring-mvc-web-application-after-deploying-on-openshift-tomcat) here is the full stacktrace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the version of the libraries that tomcat 7 is using by sshing into your application and running the following command:

```
ls ~/jbossews/lib
```

Which will output the following:

```
ls ~/jbossews/lib/
annotations-api-7.0.54.jar     
el-api-7.0.54.jar      
servlet-api.jar      
tomcat-i18n-ja-7.0.54.jar
annotations-api.jar        
el-api.jar         
tomcat7-websocket-7.0.54.jar  
tomcat-i18n-ja.jar
catalina-7.0.54.jar        
extras         
tomcat7-websocket.jar    
tomcat-jdbc-7.0.54.jar
catalina-ant-7.0.54.jar        
jasper-7.0.54.jar      
tomcat-api-7.0.54.jar    
tomcat-jdbc.jar
catalina-ant.jar           
jasper-el-7.0.54.jar    
tomcat-api.jar       
tomcat-util-7.0.54.jar
catalina.jar               
jasper-el.jar      
tomcat-coyote-7.0.54.jar     
tomcat-util.jar
commons-collections-eap6.jar       
jasper.jar         
tomcat-coyote.jar        
websocket-api-7.0.54.jar
commons-dbcp-eap6.jar          
jasper-jdt.jar     
tomcat-i18n-es-7.0.54.jar    
websocket-api.jar
commons-loggin
g-adapters-eap6.jar  
jsp-api-7.0.54.jar     
tomcat-i18n-es.jar
commons-logging-api-eap6.jar       
jsp-api.jar        
tomcat-i18n-fr-7.0.54.jar
commons-pool-eap6.jar          
servlet-api-7.0.54.jar  
tomcat-i18n-fr.jar
```

Comment: it seems tomcat 7.0.54 is not supporting <form:*> can you suggest in work around?