# Why does OpenShift Tomcat 7 (JBoss EWS 2.0) does not support <form:*> tags of spring MVC in jsps?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, tomcat, openshift

In My Spring mvc login.jsp's snippet is:

```
<form:form    method="post" action="authenticate" modelAttribute="userInfo">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">User Name</label>
                                   <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                                <form:input  path="loginID" id="username" placeholder="" />

                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group"> 
                                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                                <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                                 <form:password class="form-control" path="password" id="password" placeholder=""/>

                              </div>
                              <div>

                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Login</button>
                              </div>
                            </form:form>
```

which gives me

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP

**error** and when i modify above code to :

```
<form:form    method="post" action="authenticate" modelAttribute="userInfo">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">User Name</label>
                                   <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                                <input type="text" name="loginID" id="username"/>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group"> 
                                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                                <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                                 <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" />
                              </div>
                              <div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Login</button>
                              </div>
                            </form:form>
```

now it's works fine.
Question is why does above code doesn't compile while 2nd code runs just fine?
I need  Tomcat 7 to work with `<form:*>` tags  as rest of my application is written in `<form:*>` syntax where Tomcat 7 seems to support only `<form:form>` tag only.

> EDIT:

It seems Tomcat 7.0.54 is not supporting  tag as i run application locally on Tomcat 7.0.54 it is giving same compilation error. So how can i make run application on Tomcat 7.0.54 with  tags as i have to use openshift Tomcat only? Any Work Around?

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace completely. I wanted to know which line its throwing error. It does not makes sense to me why it would do that.

Comment: have you included tag library in ur jsp?

Comment: @minion you can see the full stacktrace [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28679924/not-able-to-run-spring-mvc-web-application-after-deploying-on-openshift-tomcat). It's strange for me too.

Comment: @javafan ofcourse I did that's why it doesn't given error for <form:form> but giving error for <form:*>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the Spring MVC Application that i deployed on **open shift Tomcat 7.0.54**, was supporting  tags except , which was then pointing to **SQL SERVER DB**  located at another location now it's pointing to open shift PostgreSQL.
And Surprisingly web app is running fine.  But I didn't get the exact reason why it was giving error earlier.
I guess there are such some reason which are possibles:

*1. JAR files which are used for compiling JSP may be corrupted at open shift Tomcat lib location.
 2. JAR version Mismatch between local tomcat Lib Jars  and open shift Tomcat lib Jars.
 3. WAR file was not build properly with right version of Jars or maybe some unexpected reason.
 4. WAR was not deployed properly in open shift tomcat.*